# Python - not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, python-2.7, string-formatting

I have started a tutorial on python, have no prior programming expirience. Currently, I am doing exercise 5, where i have to transform inches into centimeters or vice versa and a problem occurs. I am using a 2.12 python and am not planning to switch for the time being of this tutorial. I am very annoyed and frustrated why this simple problem occurs and that i can't figure out why. Here is the code:

```
centimeter = 1
inch = centimeter * 2,54
converted_value = 10 * inch

print "i decided to convert 10 inches to centimeters. Results are astonishing. %d " % converted_value
```

I ran the exercise in Windows powershell and it reported back to me this:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vaja5.py", line 28, in <module>
    print "i decided to convert 10 inches to centimeters. Results are astonishing. %d" % converted_value
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"
```

Thank you for all the help in advance. I really appreciate it

Comment: i noticed there is a part cut off after the %. all it says there is %converted_value

Comment: Note that parentheses free print (``print foo`` instead of ``print(foo)``) shows that you are using Python2. Python2 is at its end of life. Please strongly consider to use Python3; if your tutorial is for Python2, strongly consider using a more up-to-date tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`centimeter * 2,54` creates a tuple of 2 elements `(2,54)`. The problem occurs when you try to provide 2 parameters to your string (the tuple is unpacked) which has only one placeholder (`%d`).

Change:

```
inch = centimeter * 2,54
```

to:

```
inch = centimeter * 2.54
```

Comment: Maybe it's more easy to start learning by running a code directly instead of calling it from PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
inch = centimeter * 2,54
```

should be

```
inch = centimeter * 2.54
```

Your original syntax elaborates out to

```
inch = (centimeter * 2, 54)
```

so you end up assigning a tuple, which results in the formatting error.